Custom counters and environments in latexml
I wish to implement a custom environment with a referencable counter to be used with pdflatex to generate a pdf and with latexml to create a html. The following mwe demonstrates my problem.
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{question}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thechapter.\arabic{question}}

\newenvironment{question}
{\refstepcounter{question}
Question \thequestion:
}
{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 
\begin{question} \label{q:one}
    This is a question in chapter 1.
\end{question}
\end{enumerate}
Here is a reference to Question \ref{q:one}.
\end{document}

It works with pdflatex (and is quite standard, actually). But with the following commands:
latexml --dest=mwe.xml mwe
latexmlpost --dest=html/mwe.html mwe.xml

to generate mwe.html, the counter is not labelled and instead the label derives it value from the enumerate environment.

How do I get latexml to recognize the new counter+environment?

This is a known issue with \refstepcounter.  The best solution is if you can employ something that can be labeled, such as an something using amsthm.  You can also refer to this discussion.

Thank you, @teepeemm! Will try it out later today (and seems like the amsthm solution is known to work).

Thank you, teepeemm, the amsthm solution works. I shall be using it. So I am accepting your answer.
